# What are standard test metrics for memory allocators?

Tags: memory-management, performance-testing

I'm certain this question has been asked before.

As an exercise, I wish to run a series of tests to compare the performance of different memory allocators upon the same size pool of memory.

What should I be measuring?

Can someone please direct me to an existing paper or text dealing with this topic?